# Storing, editing and retrieving the d3 hierarchy in a MongoDB (keeping realtime reactivity)

Tags: mongodb, d3.js, meteor, hierarchy, publish-subscribe

I am working on [interactive tree-visualization](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/43a860bc0024792f8803bba8ca0d5ecd) powered by d3 (v4). The d3 tree diagrams are constructed with help of the **[d3 hierarchy data structure](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy)**. every node in the hierarchy keeps a refererence to its parent `node.parent` and an array with reference to the children nodes `node.children`

Thus, adding a new node (at a specific position) can be performed like this:

```
addNewNodeToParent(parent, index){      

    var newNode = d3.hierarchy({
        name: 'node-' + (++this.i),
        children: []
    });

    // added some properties to Node like parent, depth, id
    newNode.depth = parent.depth + 1;
    newNode.height = parent.height -1;
    newNode.parent = parent;
    newNode.id = this.i;

    //If no child array, create an empty array
    if(!parent.children){
        parent.children = [];
        parent.data.children = [];
    }

    //Push it to parent.children array
    parent.children.splice(index, 0, newNode);
    parent.data.children.splice(index, 0, newNode.data);

    //Update tree
    this.update(parent);
}
```

We need to provide a parent hierarchy-node. My project uses the Meteor platform/framework which comes with MongoDB and uses a publish-subscribe pattern to allow reactivity and send data to the client. The *Publish* functions can return a MongoDB `Collection.Cursor` or and array of cursors.

Although there are [recommended ways of storing trees in MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/) I am searching for a possibility to store and first and foremost RETRIEVE the d3 hierarchy nodes so I can maintain the reactivity.

The client creates a new-node => the DB is updated => the new node data and the REFERENCE TO ITS PARENT are transferred (pub-sub) to the client => client updates. Mike Bostock, creator of d3 [provided already some answers](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/issues/58) how to to find a given node within a hierarchy, so the possibilities are:

1. Returning a **hierarchy node** from the server - but how can I keep the parent-node referencewith the *publish-subscribe pattern* and `Collection.cursor` data ?
2. Keeping a **reverse-lookup structure** or **back-links** to access the hierarchy-node references - but how can I store and retrieve them, so they do not need to be computed every time the hierarchy is created ?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar to this in the past. It wasn't using MongoDB, but the concept should be the same. The best solution is to avoid using the incremental ID functionality (fails with hierarchies). Instead, use a library like [node-uuid](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-uuid) and generate a UUID for each value in your flat data structure. Once you have the flat data structure with those UUIDs, then you can use the d3.tree function to create the hierarchy for you ([here](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8329404) is an example). You will have to modify that example to use the UUIDs instead of the functionality that they are doing with the object mapping / matching. Finally, once you are ready to save the data structure back to the database, you can get the hierarchy data structure from the visualization using the `d3.select(rootNodeClassOrId).data()` function and then write your own custom function to parse through the hierarchy structure and flatten it out where you have the parent UUID attached to each node.

Hopefully that wasn't too confusing.

Alternatively, you could simply push the entire hierarchy as a single JSON string, but that could be bad if your hierarchy is extremely large and you would also be communicating object properties that aren't necessary for storage (but are required / used in the d3.tree() functionality).

Comment: I am afraid you misunderstood my question a little. There are good examples of storing hierarchical data in mongoDB - i linked some of them in my question. I am trying to  to find a way how to efficiently update the d3.hierarchy (and maintain the reactivity) without needing to parse the hierarchical data every time they change. It is possible to modify the `d3.hierarchy` directly, because the node relations are implemented as references between objects allowing to access the`hierarchy nodes` instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Check https://observablehq.com/d/c2df560e9434151d

```
mergeInAsChildOf = (B, A, nodeOfA) => {
  // merge hierarchy B in hierarchy A as child of nodeOfA

  B.parent = nodeOfA;
  nodeOfA.children.push(B);
  A = d3.hierarchy(A);
  A.each((d) => (d.data = { ...d.data.data, children: d.children })); // fixes the glitch

  return A;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).